# Shimano Deore 2x10 derailleur M6025-L with 3x Alivio M4050 crank

Tags: shimano, crankset, derailleur-front

Will my Shimano Deore front derailleur M6025 2x10 work with Shimano Alivio 3x crankset?

I'm confused because my front derailleur is not 3x design.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will work, but not optimally.

According to [the bible](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/front-derailers.html):

> "Double" front derailers will work with triples, but if the middle ring is much smaller than the big ring, they will be balky shifting up from the small to the middle chainring.

Several options:

- Drop the smallest chainring. You won't need it anyway. I have done this and I'm happy with the result.
- Learn proper front shifting technique and live with the poorer shifting of the double derailleur on a triple crankset.
- Find a triple front derailleur.
- Find a double crankset.

I used to have a very cheap bike with a double front derailleur and triple crankset. The diminished front shifting performance was not noticeable because all of the components were so poor that every shift was poor anyway, even in the rear!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 3x shifter the 2x derailleur might work, but very likely not as well as a proper 3x one. The cage is likely not deep enough to reach between the largest and smallest rings.

You imply that the derailleur is installed on the bike, how did it get there? Is this a used bike you bought or did you have the derailleur replaced?

If you have an Alivio groupset - presumably a 3x8 setup - you can obviously switch the derailleur for a proper 3x one that is compatible with your shifter and crank.

Comment: i recently buy a front deraileur and i didnt noticed that its for 2x crank

Comment: @IdolSpotlightAsiaHD then return it, and make sure you do your research next time.  There are plenty of specs on the web, just search for the brand and model number and the word "specifications"

Comment: @Idol Spotlight Asia HD The 2x derailleur should work ok given a mountain triple front drive where the tooth difference between large and middle is 10 or 12 teeth. Set up is crucial to avoid chainrub and unacceptably poor shifting.  With the Advent of 1x drivetrains, the market is engorged with front derailleurs whose prices are very low. A new, triple front derailleur can be purchased in the U.S. for $8-15, representing about 20% of the makers' recommended retail cost.